Добавить название QTableWidget в файле .ui

Как можно в файле ui задать название для таблицы?
Сейчас у последних двух стоит значение по умолчанию: "Страница"

в свйствах tabwidget есть свойство что-то типа currentText

Открыл файл .ui в vs code, и вручную прописал необходимое поле:


пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
